# Publishing contents on Facebook and update a website/app

Tags: facebook, web, synchronization

Is it possible to update a website from within a Facebook profile/fan page?
I'd like to write posts on Facebook and have my website automatically updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be polling facebook for the feed every X sec/min, if there's an update do what it is you want to. This of course is not a good solution though, and so the only way (I'm aware of) that you can have facebook push updates your way is to use the [Real-time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

The thing is that (currently) this option for the *feed* is only available for the [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object, and not the [Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) object. As it says in the docs:

```
You can subscribe to all of the User object properties except verified.
Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed...
```

And

> Note that the page topic is only used for subscribing to changes to
>   public attributes of the page (like name, category, picture etc)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So, the only way I can accomplish the task is to fetch data from a User's page feed?

Comment: I did not say that. You can still get the feed from a page, you just won't be notified on update. You can have a method on the client side that asks for the page feed via the javascript sdk, if something changed you change the UI and save the current update, then wait for X seconds and do it all over again.